# Create timestamp field on getting a POST request when using Django-tastypie

Tags: django, tastypie

I have a timestamp field in one of my Django models (let's say Comment). I have been using `Django-tastypie` for REST API. Now when a `POST` request is submitted to `/api/v1/comments/`, a new comment object is created but how do I populated the `timestamp` field in this comment. I want this timestamp to be that when the server receives the POST request.

So, how do I intercept this POST request and put this timestamp field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django has the `auto_now` and `auto_now_add` feature that you can use to automatically fill in the time on a DateTime Field.  Such as:

`created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#datefield